# php-cgi not found error constantly

Tags: php, phpstorm, fastcgi

I am trying to open a browser locally to debug what I am writing in PhpStorm. However regardless of everything I have installed PhpStorm constantly complains with "php-cgi not found" issue.

- I have installed homebrew with PHP 5.6
- I have installed fastcgi and I've read up pretty much everything there is for this error. However I am still getting this "php-cgi not found" issue
- I have installed Apache using this guide http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2015/10/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x-el-capitan/
- When I access `http://localhost/phpinfo.php` I can see the php info

[image]

Comment: What URL do you see in a browser when this message appears/when it does not work?

Comment: I get a 502 bad gateway. However I was able to resolve the issue by completely uninstalling homebrew. installing it again and clearing out all the files

Comment: Well .. I was asking about URL actually... Thing is -- you quite likely are using PhpStorm's own built-in simple web server -- at least that message clearly suggests that to me (because it does not care at all what your Apache/nginx/etc uses). If so and it does not work -- you just need to define Deployment entry where you can specify base URL that will be served by actual Apache/nginx/etc. The built-in web server is used when no Deployment is configured. ATM it may have issues with POST requests (502 response .. or POST will be empty) .. so using proper web server is a safer choice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what just worked for me - as I was having the very same issue.  Note that I was looking to install PHP 5.6.x here, so this answer conforms to that, and as of this writing, 5.6.36 was the most current version of 5.6 that brew had available. Obviously we're also dealing with MAC here.

- Open Terminal
- If you have `brew` installed, type `brew install php56`
- Once completed, your terminal window will contain a plethora of information.  One thing to look for is the path to PHP that was just installed.  Look for `If you need to have this software first in your PATH run:`.  Just below that, you'll see two paths listed. One ends in `bin`, the other in `sbin`.  You want the one that ends in `bin`.
- Open PHPStorm's PHP CLI Configuration (Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP)
- At the end of the `CLI Interpreter` box, click the `...` to open up the options.
- Click the `+` on the top-left to add a new interpreter.
- I typed "PHP 5.6" in the "Name" field... type whatever you'd like to appear.
- In the `PHP executable` field, enter the following `/usr/local/Cellar/php@5.6/5.6.36_1/bin/php-cgi` (again, this is based on the path you will find in your terminal window - described in the third step above)
- Once you enter that and leave the field, PHP Storm should detect the build and where the `php.ini` file is located, automatically.
- Click "Ok"

You're done.  This worked for me on three different installations.

Hope this helps someone.